# HTML Numerical Input Bug: infinite loop when jquery.change event called

Tags: php, html, input

I created an HTML table with PHP as follows:

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
Print "<tr>"; 
Print "<td><input id='prEff[$i]' type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='0.99' value='.85' </td>";
Print "<td>".$row['ErdEfficiency'] . "</td>";
Print "<td>".$row['TheoreticalSEC'] . "</td></tr>";

$i++;
}
```

The input cell has a jquery.change function that is called when the number is changed within the range. During debugging, clicking the up or down button once (in chrome) causes the input to run through all values until the upper or lower limit is reached. So the function is called, but only after the whole range of values is run through.

If the page is refreshed without debugging, the jquery is called, but the button sticks since it is experiencing the bug as described.

Here is the simple jquery function:

```
$('[id^="prEff["]').change(function (){
        var test = this;
        alert("hi");
});
```

Its been a difficult bug to track, and I'm not sure what is causing it. It has occurred with an onchange attribute in the input, as well as a javascript eventListener, and jquery change. It may be the way the PHP is printing the input but I've tried a couple different ways without success.

Comment: Is the unclosed input tag in your code too or just here?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle that shows your problem.  I created http://jsfiddle.net/2nExK/ and it seems to work just fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: The PHP code isn't really relevant to the question, since the problem is in the browser after PHP has done its thing; the same HTML code would do the same thing regardless of whether it was generated by PHP or not. Therefore it would be more helpful to see the actual HTML. but since you've posted the PHP, I feel I should point out that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. It is recommended to switch to the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Comment: also, which browser(s) are you testing with? And is it doing the same thing in all of them?

Comment: Thank you for the help, it was the syntax error that I didn't catch. As for the mysql functions, I am learning this stuff slowly but surely, so thank you for the fyi on deprecated functions.

Comment: Just chrome for now, but I will be testing firefox and IE as soon as the function is completed.

Comment: Glad that fixed it... I made it an answer so you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have an unclosed `<input>` tag in your code. Make sure you close it and you should be fine:

```
Print "<td><input id='prEff[$i]' type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='0.99' value='.85' /> </td>";
```